# Semantic Similarity using Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, similarity

I went through certain blogs that say Universal Sentence Encoder is used in elastic search fro semantic similarity , can we use BERT instead of ULSE , they also say the embedding search has to go through all the documents. can it be optimised.

https://www.elastic.co/blog/text-similarity-search-with-vectors-in-elasticsearch

Answer (score 1):

Sure - you can use BERT. Yet, it will induce higher runtime for transforming the data into vector embeddings. Btw, you should explore other similarity search alternatives, such as pinecone.io, which offers a managed vector search service.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely! You'll just have to make use of dense_vectors in order to search for vectors, which is what BERT works with.

For more information on dense vectors:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dense-vector.html

For more information on how to optimize embeddings search, you can check out https://www.gsitechnology.com/sites/default/files/AppNotes/GSIT-Elasticsearch-Plugin-AppBrief.pdf